# Boton Ver Mas pone imagen una sobre otra

Tags: javascript, html, css

[KomDesign](https://www.komdsign.de/) 
Hola espero que alguien tenga laguna solución para este pequeño problema.
Resulta que el botón de ver mas funciona, solo que me pone una imagen sobre otra cuando doy click y no empuja la pagina hacia abajo como debería ser. He revisado pero no he visto nada, quízas a alguien le aya sucedido lo mismo.
Espero que me puedan ayudar
Gracias [image: 1]

Comment: Comparte el codigo para poder ver que sucede

Comment: haaa lo he querido compartir pero no me deja

Comment: Hay Jorge lo he tratado compartirlo pero no me da error es que soy nuevo aquí jajajajaja. Pero estoy intentando haber como lo comparto